# python factory function best practices

Tags: design, python

Suppose I have a file `foo.py` containing a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
      ...
```

Now I want to add a function that creates a `Foo` object in a certain way from raw source data. Should I put it as a static method in Foo or as another separate function?

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
      ...
# option 1:
   @staticmethod
   def fromSourceData(sourceData):
      return Foo(processData(sourceData))

# option 2:
def makeFoo(sourceData):
   return Foo(processData(sourceData))
```

I don't know whether it's more important to be convenient for users:

```
foo1 = foo.makeFoo(sourceData)
```

or whether it's more important to maintain clear coupling between the method and the class:

```
foo1 = foo.Foo.fromSourceData(sourceData)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The choice should between a factory function and a *third* option instead; the class method:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
      ...

   @classmethod
   def fromSourceData(klass, sourceData):
      return klass(processData(sourceData))
```

Classmethod factories have the added advantage that they are inheritable. You can now create a subclass of `Foo`, and the inherited factory method would then produce instances of that subclass.

With a choice between a function and a class method, I'd choose the class method. It documents quite clearly what *kind* of object the factory is going to produce, without having to make this explicit in the function name. This becomes much clearer when you not only have multiple factory methods, but also multiple classes.

Compare the following two alternatives:

```
foo.Foo.fromFrobnar(...)
foo.Foo.fromSpamNEggs(...)
foo.Foo.someComputedVersion()
foo.Bar.fromFrobnar(...)
foo.Bar.someComputedVersion()
```

vs.

```
foo.createFooFromFrobnar()
foo.createFooFromSpamNEggs()
foo.createSomeComputedVersionFoo()
foo.createBarFromFrobnar()
foo.createSomeComputedVersionBar()
```

Even better, your end-user could import just the `Foo` class and use it for the various ways you can create it, as you have all the factory methods in one place:

```
from foo import Foo
Foo()
Foo.fromFrobnar(...)
Foo.fromSpamNEggs(...)
Foo.someComputedVersion()
```

The stdlib [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) uses class method factories extensively, and it's API is much the clearer for it.

Comment: Great answer. For more on `@classmethod`, see [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/507544)

Comment: Great focus on end-user functionality

Answer (score 1):

In Python, I usually prefer a class hierarchy over factory methods. Something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pass

    def method(self, param):
        pass

class SpecialFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        # Some processing.
        super().__init__(data)

class FromFile(Foo):
    def __init__(self, path):
        # Some processing.
        super().__init__(data)
```

I'll put the whole hierarchy (and only this one) in a module, say `foos.py`. The base class `Foo` usually implements all the methods (and as such, the interface), and is usually not constructed by the users directly. The subclasses are a mean of overwriting the base constructor, and specifying how `Foo` is to be constructed. Then I'd create a `Foo` by calling the appropriate constructor, like:

```
foo1 = mypackage.foos.SpecialFoo(param1, param2)
foo2 = mypackage.foos.FromFile('/path/to/foo')
```

I find it more elegant and flexible than factories built from static methods, class methods, or module-level functions.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but I think this is why `classmethod`s are used for different constructors. Here you have subclasses that (a) have no differences in behavior (same methods and attributes) and (b) only differ in pre-processing for initialization. I think this would make sense, however, if the subclasses had different behavior / weren't fungible.